# postfix to gmail silent delivery failure

Tags: email, postfix, spf, dkim, dmarc

With the impending turndown of free hosted Google workspace accounts, I'm trying to install my own mail server using postfix/dovecot/opendkim.  Mostly, it's working and for many of the services I've tried delivery is flowing.

However, when I send an email to a @gmail address, the google mx accepts the email, but it is silently discarded (never delivered to the target mailbox, no error reported).

PTR and A records are in alignment.  Relays are disabled.  I've got [DKIM](https://dmarcian.com/dkim-inspector/?domain=w-w-williams.com&selector=email), [SPF](https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/?domain=w-w-williams.com) and [DMARC](https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-inspector/?domain=w-w-williams.com) all set up and working correctly.  TLS is configured and available for all connections.  [RBL lists are clear](https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php?IP=165.227.22.201).  And of course Google support is not very responsive to an individual.

Is there anything I might have missed?

domain is w-w-williams.com -- my mx is m.w-w-williams.com.  Test from [CheckTLS TestSender](https://www.checktls.com/TestSender) service below:

```
SUCCESSFUL //email/test From:

Your email was sent securely using TLS.

TLS:    Successful
From:   paul@w-w-williams.com
Via:    165.227.22.201
Date:   2022-02-14 00:17:13 EST
Subject:    wetdhketjmjiv
SPF_mfrom.Record:   v=spf1 a:m.w-w-williams.com ~all
SPF_mfrom:  pass: local="w-w-williams.com: 165.227.22.201 is authorized to use 'w-w-williams.com' in 'mfrom' identity (mechanism 'a:m.w-w-williams.com' matched)"
SPF_helo:   none: local="m.w-w-williams.com: No applicable sender policy available"
DKIM:   pass: signature="@w-w-williams.com" result="pass"
DKIM_policy.sender: "o=~"(default), result="accept"
DKIM_policy.author: "o=~"(default), result="accept"
DKIM_policy.ADSP:   ""(default), result="accept"
DMARC_result:   pass
DMARC_disposition:  none
DMARC_dkim: pass
DMARC_dkim_align:   strict
DMARC_spf:  pass
DMARC_spf_align:    strict
DMARC_published.v:  DMARC1
DMARC_published.p:  quarantine
DMARC_published.sp: n/a
DMARC_published.adkim:  n/a
DMARC_published.aspf:   n/a
DMARC_published.rua:    uyvhy5ia@ag.dmarcian.com
DMARC_published.ruf:    n/a
DMARC_published.rf: n/a
DMARC_published.ri: n/a
DMARC_published.pct:    n/a
```

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find any problems with your setup, except that I don't know your DKIM selector and therefore can't check there is a valid public key. Google is very strange in this area. I had a similar problem and nothing helped except using the relay which certainly works. I swear in your case this will suddeny work after some time too, when things "cool down".

Comment: Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov.  The selector is "email", and it is working according to several different test providers.

Comment: Please add the relevant logs to your question, should look something like this: `postfix/smtp[10]: AAAAAAAAAAA: to=example@gmail.com, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c00::1a]:25, delay=..., dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1234567890 abcd1233456 - gsmtp)` - just to rule out completely unrelated problems.